# Rails: undefined method username after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently trying to add a edit function to my forum threads controller, but when I click update I get undefined method username.

Forum_threads Controller

```
class ForumThreadsController < ApplicationController
require 'forum_controller'
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :set_forum_thread, except: [:index, :new, :create]

def index
@q = ForumThread.search(params[:q])
@forum_threads = @q.result(distinct: true)
end

def show
@forum_post = ForumPost.new
@forum_posts = @forum_thread.forum_posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
end

def new
@forum_thread = ForumThread.new
@forum_thread.forum_posts.new
end

def create
@forum_thread = current_user.forum_threads.new forum_thread_params
@forum_thread.forum_posts.first.user_id = current_user.id

if @forum_thread.save
  redirect_to @forum_thread
else
  render action: :new
end
end

def edit
end

def update
if @forum_thread.update(forum_thread_params)
redirect_to @forum_thread
else
render 'edit'
end
end

private

def set_forum_thread
  @forum_thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
  @forum_post = ForumPost.find(params[:id])
end

def forum_thread_params
  params.require(:forum_thread).permit(:subject, forum_posts_attributes: [:body])
end
end
```

Error Log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass):
1:


2: <%= div_for forum_post do %>
3:
Posted by <%= forum_post.user.username %> <%= time_ago_in_words forum_post.created_at %>


4:
<%= forum_post.body %>


5: <% end %>
```

If I remove the forum_post.user.username from the HTML it'll load just fine, I've tried adding @forum_post to the update but that didn't work either...

Comment: your problem is with `forum_post.user`. there is no `user` on your `forum_post`

Comment: But there is, an unedited thread will display correctly.  I only get that error why I try to update.

Comment: Does the edit template display correctly? Could you paste show & edit views?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wuGy9F32

Comment: have you sorted out your question

Answer (score 0):

You more than likely are not submitting the user_id so when you call update with the params, user_id may be set to nil.

You can check in advance whether you see user_id in your param hash when you submit the update.

You can add a hidden field on the form for user_id and that ought to fix things.

Example:

```
<%= form_for(@forum_post) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can I get an example? Thanks